# How can I designate a unique menu item and give it unique properties?

Tags: css, menu

I am working with this menu: http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/light-opera-drop-down-menu

I would like to make the last menu option unique and have it always highlighted red, with a unique hover/active. The problem I am having is navigating the existing code so that I can add styles to my unique option. I tried identifying it via the , and then I can call it in the stylesheet

```
#cssmenu ul li.donate:hover > a {
background: red;
```

This allows me to change the hover to red, but I am unable to get it to just always be highlighted red. I tried

```
#cssmenu ul li.donate {
background:red;
}
```

but that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
#cssmenu ul:last-child li.donate:hover > a {
```

try using `:last-child`

Comment: without :hover though

Answer (score 0):

The reason your styles do not register is because the selector associated with your `background` declaration is not specific enough.  In CSS, the C stands for Cascading.  The browser trickles down or cascades multiple declarations that may or may not affect the same element.  Ultimately the styles that will be applied are the ones that come with the most specific selector.

Here's the fiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/8kfwQ/2/.  Hover over "products" and then "product 2" and you'll see a "Donate" link.

Here's the code that I've appended at the very end of the CSS in the fiddle:

```
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li.donate a {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

The selector is more specific and that's why the default maroon background gets overridden.